# Flowplay jquery tools validator - validating if box is checked. help?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-tools

I'm using the Validator jquery script provided by Flowplayer (http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/index.html) on my E-commerce checkout page. It works great by default but I'm trying to validate a set of shipping address fields ONLY if a checkbox is unchecked. Right now, it tries to validate all shipping fields, regardless. As a note, the shipping fields do need to start blank. Any ideas?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.test.com" id="myform">
<div id="billing">
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" required="required" />
<input type="text" id="test2" name="test2" required="required" />
<input type="text" id="test3" name="test3" required="required" />
</div>
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="yes" checked="checked" id="shippingCheck" />
<div id="shipping">
<input type="text" id="test4" name="test4" required="required" />
<input type="text" id="test5" name="test5" required="required" />
<input type="text" id="test6" name="test6" required="required" />
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
$("#myform").validator();
</script>
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I didn't realize this was validat**or** not jQuery validat**e**.  My answer is complete garbage!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
var shippingchecked = $("#shippingCheck:checked").val();
if (shippingchecked == undefined) $("#myform").validator();
```

It just checks whether or not the checkbox is checked and if it isn't it runs the validator.

Comment: This is close to what I need. I still do need validation for the billing fields whether the #shippingCheck is checked or unchecked.